# how does spectrum.chat hide scrollbar for secondary channel section

Tags: html, css, css-grid

The left section of a channel in https://spectrum.chat/apollo?tab=posts is scrollable but the scrollbar is hidden. How did they do it ?

In CSS class ***ctZiQt*** I found that they are using `overflow` with `grid-area` and `sticky` position but I couldn't find anything about the scrollbar itself.

I tried to recreate it but the scrollbar in my snipped is always visible. How did they hide the scrollbar ?

Thx

EDIT:

Here is how they do it. missed the class in my original code

```
.ctZiQt::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html {
        display: flex;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 1.5;
        background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
        color: rgb(22, 23, 26);
        -webkit-font-smoothing: auto;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Helvetica,
          Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji",
          "Segoe UI Symbol";
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
      }

      body {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overscroll-behavior-y: none;
      }

      #root {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }

      @media (min-width: 1648px) {
        .wrapper {
          grid-template-columns: 256px 1fr;
          grid-template-areas: "navigation main";
        }
      }
      .wrapper {
        display: grid;
        width: 100%;
        grid-template-columns: 72px 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: "navigation main";
      }

      @media (min-width: 1648px) {
        .navigation {
          width: 256px;
        }
      }

      .navigation {
        background-color: yellow;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0px;
        width: 72px;
        height: 100vh;
        grid-area: navigation / navigation / navigation / navigation;
        overflow: hidden auto;
      }

      .main {
        display: grid;
        justify-self: center;
        grid-template-columns: minmax(320px, 400px) minmax(600px, 968px);
        grid-template-rows: 100%;
        grid-template-areas: "secondary primary";
        max-width: 1392px;
        gap: 24px;
        margin: 0px 24px;
      }

      .secondary {
        background-color: green;
        height: 100vh;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 48px;
        overflow: hidden auto;
        grid-area: secondary / secondary / secondary / secondary;
      }

      .primary {
        background-color: blue;
        height: 100%;
        max-width: 968px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
        border-left: 1px solid rgb(235, 236, 237);
        border-right: 1px solid rgb(235, 236, 237);
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(235, 236, 237);
        border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
        grid-area: primary / primary / primary / primary;
      }

      .content {
        height: 3502px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      }

      .card {
        margin-top: 24px;
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: rgb(235, 236, 237);
        border-image: initial;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }

      .cardHeader {
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        justify-content: space-between;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 11;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(235, 236, 237);
        padding: 16px;
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
      }

      .cardHeaderLabel {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: rgb(36, 41, 46);
        display: flex;
        padding-right: 16px;
        flex: 1 0 auto;
      }

      .cardContent {
        height: 1950px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-direction: column;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
    </style>

    <script></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="navigation"></div>
        <div>
          <section class="main">
            <section class="secondary">
              <section class="card">
                <div class="cardHeader">
                  <div class="cardHeaderLabel">Teams</div>
                </div>
                <div class="cardContent">
                  <span>START</span>
                  <span>END</span>
                </div>
              </section>
            </section>
            <section class="primary">
              <section class="content">
                <span>START</span>
                <span>END</span>
              </section>
            </section>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not hidden for me. Apparently, it only has partial support for most browser: https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=css-scrollbar

Comment: thx for letting me know.. I am new to css and still need to get full understanding of all the browser limitations.. it's so messy :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the scrollbar with:

```
.secondary::-webkit-scrollbar {
          display: none;
}
```

Here the example:

```css
.secondary::-webkit-scrollbar {
          display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html {
        display: flex;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 1.5;
        background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
        color: rgb(22, 23, 26);
        -webkit-font-smoothing: auto;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Helvetica,
          Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji",
          "Segoe UI Symbol";
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
      }

      body {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overscroll-behavior-y: none;
      }

      #root {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }

      @media (min-width: 1648px) {
        .wrapper {
          grid-template-columns: 256px 1fr;
          grid-template-areas: "navigation main";
        }
      }
      .wrapper {
        display: grid;
        width: 100%;
        grid-template-columns: 72px 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: "navigation main";
      }

      @media (min-width: 1648px) {
        .navigation {
          width: 256px;
        }
      }

      .navigation {
        background-color: yellow;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0px;
        width: 72px;
        height: 100vh;
        grid-area: navigation / navigation / navigation / navigation;
        overflow: hidden auto;
      }

      .main {
        display: grid;
        justify-self: center;
        grid-template-columns: minmax(320px, 400px) minmax(600px, 968px);
        grid-template-rows: 100%;
        grid-template-areas: "secondary primary";
        max-width: 1392px;
        gap: 24px;
        margin: 0px 24px;
      }

      .secondary {
        background-color: green;
        height: 100vh;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 48px;
        overflow: hidden auto;
        grid-area: secondary / secondary / secondary / secondary;
      }

      .primary {
        background-color: blue;
        height: 100%;
        max-width: 968px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
        border-left: 1px solid rgb(235, 236, 237);
        border-right: 1px solid rgb(235, 236, 237);
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(235, 236, 237);
        border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
        grid-area: primary / primary / primary / primary;
      }

      .content {
        height: 3502px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      }

      .card {
        margin-top: 24px;
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: rgb(235, 236, 237);
        border-image: initial;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }

      .cardHeader {
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        justify-content: space-between;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 11;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(235, 236, 237);
        padding: 16px;
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
      }

      .cardHeaderLabel {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: rgb(36, 41, 46);
        display: flex;
        padding-right: 16px;
        flex: 1 0 auto;
      }

      .cardContent {
        height: 1950px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-direction: column;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
    </style>

    <script></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="navigation"></div>
        <div>
          <section class="main">
            <section class="secondary">
              <section class="card">
                <div class="cardHeader">
                  <div class="cardHeaderLabel">Teams</div>
                </div>
                <div class="cardContent">
                  <span>START</span>
                  <span>END</span>
                </div>
              </section>
            </section>
            <section class="primary">
              <section class="content">
                <span>START</span>
                <span>END</span>
              </section>
            </section>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks this helped me understanding it. Here is how they do it :

.ctZiQt::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    background: transparent;
}

Comment: Happy to has been useful!!